# How can I display two different tables from the same dataset in Reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services

There is a lot of posts that talk about using *different* sources for this, but I haven't found any that cover my scenario using the *same* data, while page breaking in between common groupings. I cannot adjust the stored procedure due to some compatibility issues, and am trying to figure out how to do this in the report itself.

Here is what I need to accomplish:

- We deliver items to various people in the same job order. Each person will get his own shipment list, so I group by the person delivered to, and page break after his list is finished.
- The list of sent items that the person gets should not include *pending items*. Rather, that should display as a separate table right below the first shipment list of what the person was sent.

The data returned in the stored procedure will include a flag on each detail indicating if the item is pending or not.

Our report should look like this:

```
---- Report header information ----
---- Deliver to John Joe -----

(Table with all items sent) // These need to belong to just John Joe's group

(Table with all items pending) // These need to belong to just John Joe's group
```

Page break, then on a different page

```
---- Report header information ----
---- Deliver to Max Manny --------

(Table with all items sent) // These need to belong to just Max Manny's group

(Table with all items pending) // These need to belong to just Max Manny's group
```

What I've found so far:

- Can't nest tablix controls, since dynamic cant nest inside dynamic
- It's almost like I need to be able to apply a grouped bit of data to a data context, such as a rectangle, and have both tables feed off of the same source, but havn't found a way to do this.
- If i just do two tablix controls on top of each other, the page breaking doesn't work right, since I need to break after each instance of group. But this happens for both tablix controls if I set this, so the result ordering gets messed up.

Thanks for any comments or suggestions you can provide, it's much appreciated!

Comment: You can nest groups. Your outer one would group by the recipient. The inner group would split based on that sent or pending status (use an expression if you need to). You can then apply the page break on only the outer group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion in the comments by @Martin Soles will work nicely.  Another way I've done this in the past is to use nested tables: first add a row group for the recipient, set this group to page break, add some extra rows in the group, and merge cells on the remaining rows:

[image: Table layout with single row group]

Next select your empty row and insert a table:

[image: Nesting tables within the original table]

Finally add a filter on each nested table to only show sent or pending items.  This can also be useful when you want a different number of columns on each inner table.

Comment: This approach seemed to best suit the needs. Thanks for the comments!